# Running a batch file

Tags: vb.net

How can I include a batch file or an .exe file in my setup, that runs after setup is complete?
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: What setup program are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a Visual Studio Setup Project you can add a custom action. It can't execute batch files, but it can execute scripts and executables and also call functions in some DLLs.

Here's an article with more details: [Visual Studio Setup - projects and custom actions](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/)

Be aware though, it's usually not recommended to run scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the setup program you are using. The build-in setup programs available in VS Express do not offer such possibility.

If you are looking for a free alternative, have a look at [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). Other than that, you could get away by running the external batch / application file during the first time your application runs:

```
If My.Application.Deployment.IsFirstRun then
    Process.Start("yourapp.exe")
End If
```

Comment: +1 for recommending NSIS. It's the best installer I've come across so far. It even beats the one that comes built into VS.